# How to replace all existing records with one record in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database

In my application I have multiple records that contain `username` and `domain`.
Before, I used to keep all records when they have different value in `version` field but now I want to replace them all with just one version.

For example, I have device collection that is structured as:

```
{
    username: me,
    domain: stackoverflow.com,
    version: 1
}
{
    username: me,
    domain: stackoverflow.com,
    version: 2
}
```

And kept upserting whenever there's new version.

And now I would like to have only one record that replaces all existing documents. Whenever new document with new version is `upsert`ed, all records that match username and domain will be gone and merged into the new one.

I tried `upsert: true` and `multi: true` option but it does not delete the old records.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Upsert` won't delete the old records. It can only replace or create new. ([documentation for upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/))

You'll need to clean up the old data manually. There are a few options:

1. Wait till you encounter a what before would have been a new `version` of the document and remove all versions before saving the new version. (Clean up old, then put down new).
2. Use the aggregation framework to group on `username` and `domain` to return a list of all combinations. Then, for each combination, eliminate all but the newest (you could sort on `version` to get the highest and then do a query where you use `$ne` to remove all that match everything but the highest version number). While this will really hit your database hard, you'd only need to do it once.
3. Filter the data manually in your favorite programming language and move the data to a new collection. Again, slow, but you'd do it only once.

Comment: I also thought that would be the only way. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care which one of the duplicates is kept, you can do this by creating a unique index over the two fields and specify the [`dropDups: true`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#drop-duplicates) option when calling `ensureIndex` like this:

```
db.device.ensureIndex({username: 1, domain: 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

This will force MongoDB to create the unique index by deleting documents with duplicate values leaving just one of each username/domain pairing (which seems to be just what you're looking for).

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I appreciate your answer!